# How can I convert Excel/CSV file into JSON

Tags: json, firebase

I'm trying to get data from my excel worksheet into Firebase.  It's basically a list of cities.

However, I want all of the names under one "node".

For example:

```
{ 
  "cities" : {
  "1" : "Salt Lake City, UT"
  "2" : "Park City, UT"
  }
}
```

How do I structure my data in excel, so that when I use a website it will format it that way?  Any ideas?

My excel worksheet is basically just one column:
Salt Lake City, UT
Park City, UT

etc.

Comment: First you need to decide if you're going with Firestore or Realtime Database. Your use case is really simple and I guess you can pick any of them. You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella is correct - need to tell us with database you're using. Also though, once you've 'converted' your excel data to JSON, what are you going to do with it? Are you writing an app to import the data? Did you want to use the Realtime database Import function in the console? When posting here, please give us enough information to understand what's being asked.